# CodeIgniter - Can not run $this->input->post(‘inputName’); in Modular Extensions

Tags: php, codeigniter, hmvc

As my title, I tried call that method but I got an error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function post() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\cifirst\application\modules\front\controllers\shopping.php on line 11
```

If I create a controller not in module, that method I can use very easy but in this case can not (everything code in method below can not run). This is my code:

```
 public function add_to_cart() {
  $data = array(
   'id' => $this->input->post('productId'), // line 11
   'name' => $this->input->post('productName'),
   'price' => $this->input->post('productPrice'),
   'qty' => 1,
   'options' => array('img' => $this->input->post('productImg'))
  );

  $this->load->library('MY_Cart');
  $this->cart->insert($data);

  //redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
  //echo $_POST['productId'].'-'.$_POST['productName'];
 }
```

And this code doesn't work too:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->load->library('cart');
    $this->load->helper('form');
}
```

I'm using XAMPP 1.8.1, CodeIgniter 2.1.3 and newest MX. Please help me!

Answer (score 2):

When you're using CodeIgniter functions outside of controllers, models, and views you need to get an instance of Codeigniter first.

```
class MyClass {
    private $CI;

    function __construct() {
        $this->CI =& get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->library('cart');
        $this->CI->load->helper('form');
    }

    public function someFunction() {
        $var = $this->CI->input->post("someField");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but code is still doesn't work. I tried your way yesterday. $_POST is useless too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling:

```
$this->input->post('productId');
```

inside controller than the problem is with your constructor declaration or your class name
Your construct part should contain code like this:

```
Class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->CI->load->library('cart');
        $this->CI->load->helper('form');
    }


     public function add_to_cart() 
     {
          $data = array(
                  'id' => $this->input->post('productId'), // line 11
                  'name' => $this->input->post('productName'),
                  'price' => $this->input->post('productPrice'),
                  'qty' => 1,
                  'options' => array('img' => $this->input->post('productImg'))
                  );


      }
}
```

It will work fine if you are calling from helpers function or any other classes than you should do something like this:

```
  function __construct()
  {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->CI->load->library('cart');
        $this->CI->load->helper('form');

        $this->CI =& get_instance();
  } 


  public function add_to_cart() 
  {
     $data = array(
        'id' => $this->CI->input->post('productId'), // line 11
        'name' => $this->CI->input->post('productName'),
        'price' => $this->CI->input->post('productPrice'),
        'qty' => 1,
        'options' => array('img' => $this->CI->input->post('productImg'))
        );
 }
```

Comment: I got an error in $this->CI->load->library('cart'); --> Undefined property: Shopping::$CI. I autoloaded cart library and form helper but why don't I use in modular?

Comment: did you used $this->ci =& get_instance(); inside your constructor

Comment: I copy your second sugguestion but It doesn't work. The program don't know what CI is, and if I declare private $CI, I get an other error "Call to a member function library() on a non-object". I can't use $_POST too.

Comment: go to config change $config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
to

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';

Comment: Ok. I did it. I'm only change $this->CI =& get_instance(); -> $CI =& get_instance();, it works but i try call $this->CI->input->post('productId'); but the program doesn't understand what post() is.